# Define constants in Java and use them in a collection

Tags: java, constants

I have a class similar to this:

```
class DomainTypes {
  public static final DomainType DOMAIN_1 = DomainType.of("example1.com");
  public static final DomainType DOMAIN_2 = DomainType.of("example2.com");
  public static final DomainType DOMAIN_3 = DomainType.of("example3.com");

  public static Set<DomainType> getDomainTypes() {
    return ImmutableSet.of(
      DOMAIN_1, DOMAIN_2, DOMAIN_3
    );
  }
}
```

But this is error prone. In case somebody adds a domain as a new constant, she can forget to add it into `getDomainTypes()` method. I don't want to use reflection if possible.

I need to have DomainType class in different module (jar) - kind of API module - let's say dns-api module, than DomainTypes. DomainTypes is rather configuration and it is in web-app module, which is dependent on dns-api module. With enum, I couldn't separate configuration from the object with implemented logic and I wouldn't be able to reuse dns-api module in another application. So I think tha using `enum` is not a solution for me.

Comment: Use an enum and the domain as a private field in there. Then one can use `BlubEnum.values()`.

Comment: You could use an [`enum`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) instead of a class with constants. Enums automatically have a `values()` method that gives you all the constants in the `enum`.

Comment: And also `enum` has associated classes like `EnumSet` where you can get those values as a very efficient set.

Answer (score 1):

Use an [`enum`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) instead of a class with constants:

```
public enum DomainType {
    DOMAIN_1("example1.com"),
    DOMAIN_2("example2.com"),
    DOMAIN_3("example3.com");

    private final String url;

    DomainType(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }
}
```

Enums automatically have a `values()` method which gives you an array of all the values:

```
DomainType[] domainTypes = DomainType.values();
```

Comment: I also considered an `enum`. But I need to have `DomainType` class in different module (jar) - kind of API module - let's say `dns-api` module, than `DomainTypes`. `DomainTypes` is rather configuration and it is in `web-app` module, which is dependent on `dns-api` module. With `enum`, I couldn't separate configuration from the object with implemented logic and I wouldn't be able to reuse `dns-api` module in another application.